# Helm3 with EKS cluster

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, amazon-eks

During Installation of Helm3 stable, i found **Helm3 stable does not implement tiller deployment** for fetching cluster details, it works as a Client utility only, my question is it, if it is not implementing tiller concept for fetching details, how does it connect with EKS.

**I have already installed kubectl and it is running fine, is it something like this, helm client is dependent on kubectl service?**

I performed following steps:
1.helm version
version.BuildInfo{Version:"v3.1.0", GitCommit:"b29d20baf09943e134c2fa5e1e1cab3bf93315fa", GitTreeState:"clean", GoVersion:"go1.13.7"}

2.kubectl create serviceaccount tiller --namespace kube-system
serviceaccount/tiller created

3.notepad rbac-config.yaml

4.kubectl apply -f rbac-config.yaml
clusterrolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/tiller-role-binding created

5.helm init --service-account tiller
Error: unknown flag: --service-account

I know steps 2,3,4 are not required in Helm3, but curious to know how helm3 interacts as a client service with EKS cluster.

Comment: Kubernetes has an [API](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/using-api/api-overview/) and with the right setup it can be called from either inside or outside the cluster.  There's also a little bit of discussion of this in the [Helm 3 FAQ](https://helm.sh/docs/faq/#removal-of-tiller).

Comment: but, how does Helm3 uses kubeconfig, i don't see this communication as a part of installation or post-installation, can you please explain same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like `kubectl`, helm also uses `kubeconfig` to communicate with the cluster.
So, both `kubectl` and `helm` depend on the cluster's config file rather depending on each other.

Comment: but, how does Helm3 uses kubeconfig, i don't see this communication as a part of installation or post-installation, can you please explain same.

Comment: @Abhinav07 Helm reads the `kubeconfig` from env, [here](https://github.com/helm/helm/blob/master/pkg/cli/environment.go#L106) , if the env is not provided then it looks at the default `kubeconfig` path for the config file.